# Basic table configuration for Tabulator

Tags: attributes, config, tabulator

I am new to [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info/) and was trying some things out with the help of the documentation. I am not sure if I understand the functionality of the "Persistent Module" right, but it seems suitable for my desired behaviour:
I have an app with three pages. On every page are different tables with different data. I could set them up one by one with the Tabulator options. But some settings should apply to all the tables, e.g. in all tables the second row should have an orange background. Is there some way to set up a basic table configuration (e.g. stored in an extra file, json or something like that) which then I can access in the code and basically setting up all tables with the same "look"? I hope you understand what I mean. Feel free to ask back and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The persistence module is intended for storing changes made by the user for use next time, for example if they change column sizes the table will look the same when they come back. It is not for sharing setup between tables.

If you want to ensure that the same setup options are used on all tables on a page, then you can override the default config options using the below code, from that point on any tables that are setup will have that setting. for example if you wanted every table on the page to have the same layout mode, you could add the above code before you create your first table, all tables created after that point would have that layout mode unless you set something differently in its constructor:

```js
Tabulator.prototype.defaultOptions.layout = "fitColumns";
```

More details on this can be found in the [Default Options](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/modules#default) documentation

If you want to persiste consistent styling across tables then i recomend just using CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this out and yeah it does work perfectly for tables on a single page. Also understanding of persistence module was achieved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, but I dont think it will do what you are indicating here you want to (ie. row[1].style.backgroundColor = 'orange';)

But you can certainly store whatever you want in Persistence, because you can define a persistenceReaderFunc that returns whatever data you want to the Tabulator to assist in layout options, and for other configuration options, store that as well, but just not return it in the persistenceReaderFunc.

ie. if you store

```
{ 
    "notfortabulator" : { "row2color": "orange" },
    "fortabulator" : [
        { "field":"fieldName","width":63,"visible":false }
    ],
}
```

you only have to return the fortabulator field to Tabulator for it to do its thing with the persistence, and still have the data for you to configure your second row with a color option and look it up

Comment: thank you for your answer. it was helpful for pushing me in the right direction.